# Changing Refresh button to stop button when pressed

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am coding a browser with pyqt5 on visual studio code and i dont know how to change refresh button to stop when i press to refresh button. I searched for it but i didnt find anything for it. When i searched up on youtube to make a browser it just added another button as "stop" but i want to make with changing. How can i do?

Code line of refresh button:

```py
reload_btn = QAction(QIcon('yineletus.png'),'Yinele', self)
reload_btn.setStatusTip("Sayfayı yinelersin.")
reload_btn.triggered.connect(lambda:self.tabs.currentWidget().reload())
navtb.addAction(reload_btn)
```

Comment: Please don't post code as an image.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @Kitswas did you upvote since OP updated the image to text?

Comment: @gbeaven I did. :) Thanks for reminding.

Comment: Are you using the same action for *all* tabs?

Comment: @musicamante yea but changing trigger example: home_btn.triggered.connect(lambda:self.tabs.currentWidget().home())

Answer (score 0):

QWebEngineView has various helper signals that can be used for that, most importantly:

- [`loadStarted`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#loadStarted)
- [`loadFinished`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#loadFinished)

In a simple situation, you would just connect those signals to a function that changes the icon (and, possibly, text and tooltip).

Unfortunately, you are sharing the same tool bar for *all* pages, which makes things more complex (and that's also a reason for which modern browsers always have an individual tool bar for each page).

In order to achieve this, you cannot directly connect the `triggered` signal, but you have to pass through a function that actually checks the status of the current active page, and eventually trigger the related web action.

The icon change, instead, must happen upon different events: when the current tab is changed (since the previous page may have finished the loading and the new one not), when the loading starts (via user request or not) and, obviously when it finishes.

As far as I know, there is no *direct* way to know the *current* status of a web page loading. The only way I could find to get that is by checking if the [`pageAction()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#pageAction) for the `Stop` or `Reload` actions `isEnabled()`: if the former is enabled, it means that the page is loading, and vice versa for the latter.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngine import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

class WebView(QWebEngineView):
    '''
        A basic subclass to provide some helper functions
    '''

    def canGoForward(self):
        return self.pageAction(QWebEnginePage.Forward).isEnabled()

    def canGoBackward(self):
        return self.pageAction(QWebEnginePage.Back).isEnabled()

    def stopReloadActions(self):
        return (
            self.pageAction(QWebEnginePage.Stop), 
            self.pageAction(QWebEnginePage.Reload)
        )

    def canStop(self):
        return self.pageAction(QWebEnginePage.Stop).isEnabled()

    def canReload(self):
        return self.pageAction(QWebEnginePage.Reload).isEnabled()


class Browser(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        toolBar = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(toolBar)

        style = self.style()
        self.backButton = QToolButton(
            icon=style.standardIcon(style.SP_ArrowLeft),
            focusPolicy=Qt.NoFocus)
        self.forwardButton = QToolButton(
            icon=style.standardIcon(style.SP_ArrowRight),
            focusPolicy=Qt.NoFocus)
        self.stopReloadButton = QToolButton(focusPolicy=Qt.NoFocus)
        self.urlEdit = QLineEdit()

        self.reloadIcon = style.standardIcon(style.SP_BrowserReload)
        self.stopIcon = style.standardIcon(style.SP_BrowserStop)
        
        toolBar.addWidget(self.backButton)
        toolBar.addWidget(self.forwardButton)
        toolBar.addWidget(self.stopReloadButton)
        toolBar.addWidget(self.urlEdit)

        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)

        self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.goBack)
        self.forwardButton.clicked.connect(self.goForward)
        self.stopReloadButton.clicked.connect(self.stopOrReload)
        self.tabWidget.currentChanged.connect(self.updateToolBar)
        self.urlEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.setUrl)

        for url in ('stackoverflow.com', 'google.com', 'python.org'):
            self.addTab(url)

    def setUrl(self):
        url = self.urlEdit.text().strip()
        if url:
            self.tabWidget.currentWidget().setUrl(QUrl.fromUserInput(url))

    def addTab(self, url=''):
        view = WebView()
        view.titleChanged.connect(self.updateTitle)
        view.loadStarted.connect(self.updateToolBar)
        view.loadFinished.connect(self.updateToolBar)
        view.urlChanged.connect(self.updateToolBar)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(view, '')
        view.setUrl(QUrl.fromUserInput(url))

    def updateTitle(self, title):
        view = self.sender()
        tab = self.tabWidget.indexOf(view)
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(tab, 
            self.fontMetrics().elidedText(title, Qt.ElideRight, 120))
        self.tabWidget.setTabToolTip(tab, title)
        if view == self.tabWidget.currentWidget():
            self.setWindowTitle(view.title() + ' - My Browser')

    def updateToolBar(self):
        view = self.tabWidget.currentWidget()
        if (
            isinstance(self.sender(), QWebEngineView)
            and view != self.sender()
        ):
            return
        view = self.tabWidget.currentWidget()
        self.urlEdit.setText(view.url().toString())
        stopAction, reloadAction = view.stopReloadActions()
        self.stopReloadButton.setEnabled(
            stopAction.isEnabled() or reloadAction.isEnabled())
        if stopAction.isEnabled():
            self.stopReloadButton.setIcon(self.stopIcon)
        elif reloadAction.isEnabled():
            self.stopReloadButton.setIcon(self.reloadIcon)
        self.backButton.setEnabled(view.canGoBackward())
        self.forwardButton.setEnabled(view.canGoForward())
        self.setWindowTitle(view.title() + ' - My Browser')

    def goBack(self):
        self.tabWidget.currentWidget().back()

    def goForward(self):
        self.tabWidget.currentWidget().forward()

    def stopOrReload(self):
        view = self.tabWidget.currentWidget()
        stopAction, reloadAction = view.stopReloadActions()
        if stopAction.isEnabled():
            view.stop()
        elif reloadAction.isEnabled():
            view.reload()


app = QApplication([])
browser = Browser()
browser.show()
app.exec()
```

Unfortunately, there is a problem. A huge one.

A couple of bugs affecting Qt 5.15 sometimes results in the QWebEnginePage not properly updating the loading status of the page: sometimes the load signals can become inconsistent when a complex page starts a request under certain circumstances (for instance, an asynchronous request for a resource loading). You can see that behavior after some attempts in doing some research on Google.

The huge problem is that, while the bug has been fixed, it was only done since Qt 5.15.5, and the latest standard release (the open source one, not the commercial) is only up to 5.15.4.

This means that you are left with the following choices:

- pay for the commercial license (note: the Qt license, not the PyQt one);
- use a version that is not affected by the bug (5.14, and, possibly, some early 5.15 versions);
- build Qt on your own and release your program with that;
- switch to Qt6;
- find a "hacky" workaround for that problem, using some timeouts and overriding functions such as [`acceptNavigationRequest()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#acceptNavigationRequest);

The choice depends on how you want to deploy and distribute your program.

<sup>Note that the above example doesn't consider features like creating new windows (eg. popups) or closing tabs. Obviously, you have to implement those on your own.</sup>